# Multi Step Form with Progress Bar using jQuery and CSS3, input not working in DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css, progress-bar

I downloaded the same "Multi Step Form with Progress Bar using jQuery and CSS3".

I was able to show the fieldsets with divs in for more forms or images so displaying the content in the fieldset is not the problem. it is the actual button, the next button that doesn't work unless outside the div.

This is a problem as the button (as well as the previous button) on the next fieldset needs to be placed in a div (for styling purposes)

so while this proceeds to next step

```
<fieldset>
<h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
<h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
<button type="button" class="next action-button btn btn-primary">
  Next Step</span>
</button>
```

This one does not

```
<fieldset>
<h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
<h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
<div class="pull-right">
  <button type="button" class="next action-button btn btn-primary">
      Next Step
  </button>                  
</div>
```

The button just disappears. Well moves left, then fades. :)
The code I have is below.

```js
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;
 
 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
 
 //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
 
 //show the next fieldset
 next_fs.show(); 
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
   scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
   left = (now * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
   next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
  }, 
  duration: 800, 
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  }, 
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;
 
 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
 
 //de-activate current step on progressbar
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");
 
 //show the previous fieldset
 previous_fs.show(); 
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
   scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
   left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({'left': left});
   previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
  }, 
  duration: 800, 
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  }, 
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
 return false;
})

jQuery.easing.jswing=jQuery.easing.swing;jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing,{def:"easeOutQuad",swing:function(e,f,a,h,g){return jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def](e,f,a,h,g)},easeInQuad:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*(f/=g)*f+a},easeOutQuad:function(e,f,a,h,g){return -h*(f/=g)*(f-2)+a},easeInOutQuad:function(e,f,a,h,g){if((f/=g/2)<1){return h/2*f*f+a}return -h/2*((--f)*(f-2)-1)+a},easeInCubic:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*(f/=g)*f*f+a},easeOutCubic:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*((f=f/g-1)*f*f+1)+a},easeInOutCubic:function(e,f,a,h,g){if((f/=g/2)<1){return h/2*f*f*f+a}return h/2*((f-=2)*f*f+2)+a},easeInQuart:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*(f/=g)*f*f*f+a},easeOutQuart:function(e,f,a,h,g){return -h*((f=f/g-1)*f*f*f-1)+a},easeInOutQuart:function(e,f,a,h,g){if((f/=g/2)<1){return h/2*f*f*f*f+a}return -h/2*((f-=2)*f*f*f-2)+a},easeInQuint:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*(f/=g)*f*f*f*f+a},easeOutQuint:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*((f=f/g-1)*f*f*f*f+1)+a},easeInOutQuint:function(e,f,a,h,g){if((f/=g/2)<1){return h/2*f*f*f*f*f+a}return h/2*((f-=2)*f*f*f*f+2)+a},easeInSine:function(e,f,a,h,g){return -h*Math.cos(f/g*(Math.PI/2))+h+a},easeOutSine:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*Math.sin(f/g*(Math.PI/2))+a},easeInOutSine:function(e,f,a,h,g){return -h/2*(Math.cos(Math.PI*f/g)-1)+a},easeInExpo:function(e,f,a,h,g){return(f==0)?a:h*Math.pow(2,10*(f/g-1))+a},easeOutExpo:function(e,f,a,h,g){return(f==g)?a+h:h*(-Math.pow(2,-10*f/g)+1)+a},easeInOutExpo:function(e,f,a,h,g){if(f==0){return a}if(f==g){return a+h}if((f/=g/2)<1){return h/2*Math.pow(2,10*(f-1))+a}return h/2*(-Math.pow(2,-10*--f)+2)+a},easeInCirc:function(e,f,a,h,g){return -h*(Math.sqrt(1-(f/=g)*f)-1)+a},easeOutCirc:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*Math.sqrt(1-(f=f/g-1)*f)+a},easeInOutCirc:function(e,f,a,h,g){if((f/=g/2)<1){return -h/2*(Math.sqrt(1-f*f)-1)+a}return h/2*(Math.sqrt(1-(f-=2)*f)+1)+a},easeInElastic:function(f,h,e,l,k){var i=1.70158;var j=0;var g=l;if(h==0){return e}if((h/=k)==1){return e+l}if(!j){j=k*0.3}if(g<Math.abs(l)){g=l;var i=j/4}else{var i=j/(2*Math.PI)*Math.asin(l/g)}return -(g*Math.pow(2,10*(h-=1))*Math.sin((h*k-i)*(2*Math.PI)/j))+e},easeOutElastic:function(f,h,e,l,k){var i=1.70158;var j=0;var g=l;if(h==0){return e}if((h/=k)==1){return e+l}if(!j){j=k*0.3}if(g<Math.abs(l)){g=l;var i=j/4}else{var i=j/(2*Math.PI)*Math.asin(l/g)}return g*Math.pow(2,-10*h)*Math.sin((h*k-i)*(2*Math.PI)/j)+l+e},easeInOutElastic:function(f,h,e,l,k){var i=1.70158;var j=0;var g=l;if(h==0){return e}if((h/=k/2)==2){return e+l}if(!j){j=k*(0.3*1.5)}if(g<Math.abs(l)){g=l;var i=j/4}else{var i=j/(2*Math.PI)*Math.asin(l/g)}if(h<1){return -0.5*(g*Math.pow(2,10*(h-=1))*Math.sin((h*k-i)*(2*Math.PI)/j))+e}return g*Math.pow(2,-10*(h-=1))*Math.sin((h*k-i)*(2*Math.PI)/j)*0.5+l+e},easeInBack:function(e,f,a,i,h,g){if(g==undefined){g=1.70158}return i*(f/=h)*f*((g+1)*f-g)+a},easeOutBack:function(e,f,a,i,h,g){if(g==undefined){g=1.70158}return i*((f=f/h-1)*f*((g+1)*f+g)+1)+a},easeInOutBack:function(e,f,a,i,h,g){if(g==undefined){g=1.70158}if((f/=h/2)<1){return i/2*(f*f*(((g*=(1.525))+1)*f-g))+a}return i/2*((f-=2)*f*(((g*=(1.525))+1)*f+g)+2)+a},easeInBounce:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h-jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce(e,g-f,0,h,g)+a},easeOutBounce:function(e,f,a,h,g){if((f/=g)<(1/2.75)){return h*(7.5625*f*f)+a}else{if(f<(2/2.75)){return h*(7.5625*(f-=(1.5/2.75))*f+0.75)+a}else{if(f<(2.5/2.75)){return h*(7.5625*(f-=(2.25/2.75))*f+0.9375)+a}else{return h*(7.5625*(f-=(2.625/2.75))*f+0.984375)+a}}}},easeInOutBounce:function(e,f,a,h,g){if(f<g/2){return jQuery.easing.easeInBounce(e,f*2,0,h,g)*0.5+a}return jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce(e,f*2-g,0,h,g)*0.5+h*0.5+a}});
```

```css
/*custom font*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
 height: 100%;
 /*Image only BG fallback*/
 
 /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
 background: 
  linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
}

body {
 font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
 width: 400px;
 margin: 50px auto;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
 background: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 padding: 20px 30px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 10%;
 
 /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
 position: relative;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
 display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
 padding: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: montserrat;
 color: #2C3E50;
 font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
 width: 100px;
 background: #27AE60;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
 font-size: 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #2C3E50;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #666;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
 /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
 counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 9px;
 width: 33.33%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
 content: counter(step);
 counter-increment: step;
 width: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 display: block;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #333;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 background: white;
 position: absolute;
 left: -50%;
 top: 9px;
 z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
 /*connector not needed before the first step*/
 content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
 background: #27AE60;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Multi Step Form with Progress Bar using jQuery and CSS3</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform">
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
    <li>Social Profiles</li>
    <li>Personal Details</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
      
        <button type="button" class="next action-button btn btn-primary">
        Next Step WORKING </button>                
      <hr/> 
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="next action-button btn btn-primary">
        Next Step NOT WORKING </button>                
      </div>  
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
    <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
    <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
    <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
      <div class="pull-left">
        <button type="button" class="previous action-button btn btn-primary">previous NOT WORKING </button>                
      </div> 
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="next action-button btn btn-primary">
        Next Step NOT WORKING </button>                
      </div>     
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
    <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
  </fieldset>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you not use a child div inside the div of the form for "styling purposes"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jquery is using `$.parent()` when you click the next button to target the current `fieldset` and `$.parent().next()` to target the next `fieldset`. When you wrap the next button in a `div`, that `div` is now the parent - not the `fieldset`. Just change `current_fs` and `next_fs` to find the `$.closest('fieldset')` instead of using `$.parent()`

```js
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;
 
 current_fs = $(this).closest('fieldset');
 next_fs = current_fs.next();
 
 //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
 
 //show the next fieldset
 next_fs.show(); 
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
   scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
   left = (now * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
   next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
  }, 
  duration: 800, 
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  }, 
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;
 
 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
 
 //de-activate current step on progressbar
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");
 
 //show the previous fieldset
 previous_fs.show(); 
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
   scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
   left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({'left': left});
   previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
  }, 
  duration: 800, 
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  }, 
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
 return false;
})

jQuery.easing.jswing=jQuery.easing.swing;jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing,{def:"easeOutQuad",swing:function(e,f,a,h,g){return jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def](e,f,a,h,g)},easeInQuad:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*(f/=g)*f+a},easeOutQuad:function(e,f,a,h,g){return -h*(f/=g)*(f-2)+a},easeInOutQuad:function(e,f,a,h,g){if((f/=g/2)<1){return h/2*f*f+a}return -h/2*((--f)*(f-2)-1)+a},easeInCubic:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*(f/=g)*f*f+a},easeOutCubic:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*((f=f/g-1)*f*f+1)+a},easeInOutCubic:function(e,f,a,h,g){if((f/=g/2)<1){return h/2*f*f*f+a}return h/2*((f-=2)*f*f+2)+a},easeInQuart:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*(f/=g)*f*f*f+a},easeOutQuart:function(e,f,a,h,g){return -h*((f=f/g-1)*f*f*f-1)+a},easeInOutQuart:function(e,f,a,h,g){if((f/=g/2)<1){return h/2*f*f*f*f+a}return -h/2*((f-=2)*f*f*f-2)+a},easeInQuint:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*(f/=g)*f*f*f*f+a},easeOutQuint:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*((f=f/g-1)*f*f*f*f+1)+a},easeInOutQuint:function(e,f,a,h,g){if((f/=g/2)<1){return h/2*f*f*f*f*f+a}return h/2*((f-=2)*f*f*f*f+2)+a},easeInSine:function(e,f,a,h,g){return -h*Math.cos(f/g*(Math.PI/2))+h+a},easeOutSine:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*Math.sin(f/g*(Math.PI/2))+a},easeInOutSine:function(e,f,a,h,g){return -h/2*(Math.cos(Math.PI*f/g)-1)+a},easeInExpo:function(e,f,a,h,g){return(f==0)?a:h*Math.pow(2,10*(f/g-1))+a},easeOutExpo:function(e,f,a,h,g){return(f==g)?a+h:h*(-Math.pow(2,-10*f/g)+1)+a},easeInOutExpo:function(e,f,a,h,g){if(f==0){return a}if(f==g){return a+h}if((f/=g/2)<1){return h/2*Math.pow(2,10*(f-1))+a}return h/2*(-Math.pow(2,-10*--f)+2)+a},easeInCirc:function(e,f,a,h,g){return -h*(Math.sqrt(1-(f/=g)*f)-1)+a},easeOutCirc:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*Math.sqrt(1-(f=f/g-1)*f)+a},easeInOutCirc:function(e,f,a,h,g){if((f/=g/2)<1){return -h/2*(Math.sqrt(1-f*f)-1)+a}return h/2*(Math.sqrt(1-(f-=2)*f)+1)+a},easeInElastic:function(f,h,e,l,k){var i=1.70158;var j=0;var g=l;if(h==0){return e}if((h/=k)==1){return e+l}if(!j){j=k*0.3}if(g<Math.abs(l)){g=l;var i=j/4}else{var i=j/(2*Math.PI)*Math.asin(l/g)}return -(g*Math.pow(2,10*(h-=1))*Math.sin((h*k-i)*(2*Math.PI)/j))+e},easeOutElastic:function(f,h,e,l,k){var i=1.70158;var j=0;var g=l;if(h==0){return e}if((h/=k)==1){return e+l}if(!j){j=k*0.3}if(g<Math.abs(l)){g=l;var i=j/4}else{var i=j/(2*Math.PI)*Math.asin(l/g)}return g*Math.pow(2,-10*h)*Math.sin((h*k-i)*(2*Math.PI)/j)+l+e},easeInOutElastic:function(f,h,e,l,k){var i=1.70158;var j=0;var g=l;if(h==0){return e}if((h/=k/2)==2){return e+l}if(!j){j=k*(0.3*1.5)}if(g<Math.abs(l)){g=l;var i=j/4}else{var i=j/(2*Math.PI)*Math.asin(l/g)}if(h<1){return -0.5*(g*Math.pow(2,10*(h-=1))*Math.sin((h*k-i)*(2*Math.PI)/j))+e}return g*Math.pow(2,-10*(h-=1))*Math.sin((h*k-i)*(2*Math.PI)/j)*0.5+l+e},easeInBack:function(e,f,a,i,h,g){if(g==undefined){g=1.70158}return i*(f/=h)*f*((g+1)*f-g)+a},easeOutBack:function(e,f,a,i,h,g){if(g==undefined){g=1.70158}return i*((f=f/h-1)*f*((g+1)*f+g)+1)+a},easeInOutBack:function(e,f,a,i,h,g){if(g==undefined){g=1.70158}if((f/=h/2)<1){return i/2*(f*f*(((g*=(1.525))+1)*f-g))+a}return i/2*((f-=2)*f*(((g*=(1.525))+1)*f+g)+2)+a},easeInBounce:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h-jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce(e,g-f,0,h,g)+a},easeOutBounce:function(e,f,a,h,g){if((f/=g)<(1/2.75)){return h*(7.5625*f*f)+a}else{if(f<(2/2.75)){return h*(7.5625*(f-=(1.5/2.75))*f+0.75)+a}else{if(f<(2.5/2.75)){return h*(7.5625*(f-=(2.25/2.75))*f+0.9375)+a}else{return h*(7.5625*(f-=(2.625/2.75))*f+0.984375)+a}}}},easeInOutBounce:function(e,f,a,h,g){if(f<g/2){return jQuery.easing.easeInBounce(e,f*2,0,h,g)*0.5+a}return jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce(e,f*2-g,0,h,g)*0.5+h*0.5+a}});
```

```css
/*custom font*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
 height: 100%;
 /*Image only BG fallback*/
 
 /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
 background: 
  linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
}

body {
 font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
 width: 400px;
 margin: 50px auto;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
 background: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 padding: 20px 30px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 10%;
 
 /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
 position: relative;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
 display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
 padding: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: montserrat;
 color: #2C3E50;
 font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
 width: 100px;
 background: #27AE60;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
 font-size: 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #2C3E50;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #666;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
 /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
 counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 9px;
 width: 33.33%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
 content: counter(step);
 counter-increment: step;
 width: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 display: block;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #333;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 background: white;
 position: absolute;
 left: -50%;
 top: 9px;
 z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
 /*connector not needed before the first step*/
 content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
 background: #27AE60;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Multi Step Form with Progress Bar using jQuery and CSS3</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform">
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
    <li>Social Profiles</li>
    <li>Personal Details</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
      
        <button type="button" class="next action-button btn btn-primary">
        Next Step WORKING </button>                
      <hr/> 
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="next action-button btn btn-primary">
        Next Step NOT WORKING </button>                
      </div>  
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
    <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
    <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
    <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
      <div class="pull-left">
        <button type="button" class="previous action-button btn btn-primary">previous NOT WORKING </button>                
      </div> 
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="next action-button btn btn-primary">
        Next Step NOT WORKING </button>                
      </div>     
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
    <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
  </fieldset>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael-Coker!! I even tried a table instead of divs, made text links styled as buttons, anything for a workaround and came up empty. :). Didn't think about the target and know I certainly wouldn't have figured it out. 

Seeing that there is a next and previous, and based on your fabulous solution I have added same to click function  $(".previous").
 
 `current_fs = $(this).closest('fieldset');`

and it works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: looks like I was too quick. Next was right. Previous... div was disappearing :). so a quick change of 
 `previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();`

to  
 `previous_fs = current_fs.prev();`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again Michael. Consider question closed :)

The correct adjusted code below for allowing inputs / buttons in divs within the fieldset for the "Multi Step Form with Progress Bar using jQuery and CSS3"

```
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).closest('fieldset');
    next_fs = current_fs.next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).closest('fieldset');
    previous_fs = current_fs.prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})
```